# C# open file exception

Tags: c#, file, exception, csv

i have a C# form having troubles with file operations.

Here's how it works :

When the user click on the "start" button, the program begins.
It opens the file (if exists?), check the header of this file and modify a boolean if this header exists.

Then, it opens the file again, to put a header (if non exists) and other infos, or just infos (if header exists)

Here's the code :

```
public bool enteteExiste = false;

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       verifieEntete();
       //INSERTION DE L'ENTETE DU FICHIER CSV
       writeToCsv = new StreamWriter(boxFilePath.Text + "\\" + filename, true);
       canAcces = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Droits d'accès au dossier insuffisant OU fichier déjà ouvert" + Environment.NewLine + "Assurez vous d'avoir fermé le fichier et de disposer des droits requis" + Environment.NewLine + "Arrêt de la procédure");
    }
}

public void verifieEntete()
{
    string absolutFilePath = boxFilePath.Text + '\\' + filename;
    String[] fileContent = File.ReadAllText(absolutFilePath).Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
        if (fileContent[i].Contains("MAC;SERIAL;IP;MODELE;MODULE-EXT"))
            enteteExiste = true ;    
}
```

When file already exists, program runs perfectly, 
When file does not exists, program goes into catch Exception.

Is ReadAllTest() not supposed to check wether file exists or not ?
Should i add a special Exception catch "filenotfound", and create it ?

Comment: You should check if your file exists first with File.Exists().
Et "insuffisant" prend un "s" a la fin (ce sont les droits qui sont insuffisants) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `File.ReadAllText` state explicitly that it will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file doesn't exist. So yes, you have to explicitly check for its existence.

It's best not to rely on Exceptions for something that can easily be checked beforehand. Both because of potential performance issues (catching an exception is *a lot* slower than a simple if test), and both for code clarity and readability - an if/else branching is usually easier to understand and structure than a try/catch block. This way you can handle the error *before* it happens, and fix it (like, say, creating the file if necessary)

```
public void verifieEntete()
{
    string absolutFilePath = boxFilePath.Text + '\\' + filename;
    if (!File.Exists(absolutFilePath) // <--- ADD EXPLICIT CHECK
    {
         // Create the file here. 
    }

    // Now we know the file is *sure* to exist, because we handled it 
    // explicitly.
    String[] fileContent = File.ReadAllText(absolutFilePath).Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
        if (fileContent[i].Contains("MAC;SERIAL;IP;MODELE;MODULE-EXT"))
            enteteExiste = true ;    
}
```

Comment: Do you think i can call him recursively when created the file? something like (after your code) : else { *create file* ; verifieEntete();

Comment: It still throw me an Exception, but creates the file...Why?
The raised exception is "Cannot access to file c:\....." already in use

Comment: Where does it throw the exception, and what exception does it throw?

Comment: (Also, note that even if your *first* line contains the MAC;SERIAL... string, you'll still go over the entire file, rather than breaking early)

Comment: This is a different issue. Read the exception and what it means: the file is in use, probably by the code you use to *create* it. Be sure to close the file, and search here on SO or elsewhere on this error.

Comment: Nope, it's the same issue, Creating a file with File.Create lock resources used for it. So when creating the file with File.Create(filepath), you have to add .Close() to the end of the line.
Thanks for help !